# how to make drop-down lists in sql report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

Could anybody help, please?

I'm confused a bit about where that feature could be find in VS and some docs about it
thanks in advance

[image: report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is showing a feature called **Drilldown**.

With this, you can show or hide report items by setting the **ToggleItem** property to a textbox outside of the item Scope.

[image]

You can see more information at Books Online:

[Hiding and Showing Report Items by Adding Drilldown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207042%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

[Add an Expand/Collapse Action to an Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220405%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).